# Working with Doctrine ORM: Custom repository

Tags: php, orm, doctrine, code-completion

I have about 10 entities: \App\Entity\User, \App\Entity\ Group, ...

For each of them has its own repository: \App\Repository\UserRepository, ... In each of a dozen methods.

In Doctrine for access method:

```php
$userRepository = $em->getRepository('App\Entity\User');
```

However, it is not convenient, because lost code completion.

Question: how to organize work with repositories, without increasing the static connection code?
Should I use a static method get?

```php
class UserRepository extends EntityRepository
{
     /**
      * @static
      * @return \App\Repository\UserRepository
      */
     public static function get ()
     {
         $em = \Registry::getInstance()->get('em');
         return $em->getRepository('App\Entity\User');
     }
}
```

I watched as implemented to work with the doctrine of the symphony, but there is the same problem with code completion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there's any entirely clean solutions to this.

Your options basically boil down to two:

- Static getters as you show. **Problem**: hard to unit test, hides dependencies to things like the Registry class, requires manually adding them
- Using some kind of a factory with getters. **Problem**: requires manually adding the factory methods

I don't really think it's such a big deal. Repositories don't have that many methods in them usually anyway, so it's not that hard to remember (or check)

However, one thing you could also try is this:

```
/* @var My\Repository\FooRepository */
$repo = $em->getRepository('My\Repository\FooRepository');
```

This should activate completion for `$repo` in most IDE's. It still involves some extra typing tho.

Answer (score -1):

$this->_em is available from within the repository.  I use it all the time